# How to fix inlcude_once showing php as output only error in dreamweaver?

Tags: php, html, css, dreamweaver

I'm building a website on Dreamweaver using PHP and its only the start of it.
include_once doesn't show the image. It only shows PHP in the design tab.

I've tried include also but that is also not working. I've tried for other files too, still the same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>The Pickzone</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
  <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
    <?php include_once('template_header.php');?>
    <div id="pageContent">test</div>
    <?php include_once('template_footer.php');?>

  </div>
```

Comment: Does the file have the `.php` extension?

Comment: Yes Sir. It does have .php extension.

Comment: Are you running this on a web server running PHP?

Comment: No sir. Im running this on a local server for now using dreamweaver. The problem that is happening is that in the 'template_header.php' tab I have inserted images, tables etc.. There is a tab 'index.php' where I used               
 <?php include_once('template_header.php');?>. In this tab's design tab, it doesnot show me the images or tables. It only shows a small text 'php'.

Comment: I've never used DreamWeaver so I'm not sure. But, the PHP files need to be processed by a web server running PHP. Maybe check out [this article](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html)

Comment: Thank you sir for the help but my problem lies is DreamWeaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `__DIR__` in front of your includes to provide the full path on the disk. E.g. `/var/www/path/to/file/on/disk/`.

```
<?php include_once __DIR__ . 'template_header.php';?>
<div id="pageContent">test</div>
<?php include_once __DIR__ . 'template_footer.php';?>
```

See the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.include-once.php) for more information.